# Large structures parsed using boost-spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I can compile the employee example code found on [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/employee.cpp).

If I extend the structure with 8 more strings like so:

```
struct employee
{
    int age;
    std::string surname;
    std::string forename;
    std::string a1;
    std::string a2;
    std::string a3;
    std::string a4;
    std::string a5;
    std::string a6;
    std::string a7;
    std::string a8;
    double salary;
};
```

(And of course I extend the BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT and the grammar as well), then I get the following error, when I try to compile:

```
../include/boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp:26:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct boost::fusion::detail::as_vector<12>’
../include/boost/fusion/container/vector/detail/as_vector.hpp:26:12: error: declaration of ‘struct boost::fusion::detail::as_vector<12>’
```

I have found that this happens if my struct has > 10 items. Two questions:

1. Why this limitation?
2. How do I work around it?

Any input is welcome.

Comment: Define FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE to whatever cap you want ( but stay reasonable, as it's likely limited due to being heavy on compile times ) and I'll bet it works.

Comment: By the way, using boost 1.48 and g++ 4.6.3. Compile command: g++ -I../include -ggdb -Wall -oemployee employee.cpp

Comment: @Ylisar: That's it! Thanks a lot. Could you convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define `FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE` to whatever cap you want, take a look in `boost/fusion/container/vector/limits.hpp` for the default define. `boost/fusion/container/vector.hpp`then conditionally includes pre processed source depending on the cap.